# What does tensorflow tf.keras.input "tensor" parameter do?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

The official document does not state clearly what this parameter actually does. Can anyone please explain it with an example?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when you set `shape` argument and optionally `dtype`, it creates a placeholder for the input:

```
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(w,h,c))
```

Passing `tensor` argument is another way to specify the input params (using [`tf.TypeSpec`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TypeSpec)) with another tensor:

```
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(tensor=some_tensor)
```

It is meant to specify the input of a model by the output of another model or layer.

For example, here is `model1`:

```
model1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
                   tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(28,28,1)),
                   tf.keras.layers.Flatten()])
```

And I can specify the input of `model2` by the output of `model1` like this:

```
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(tensor=model1.output)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation="relu")(input)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(x)
model2 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
model2.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "model_01"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_20 (InputLayer)        [(None, 784)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_42 (Dense)             (None, 12)                9420      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_43 (Dense)             (None, 10)                130       
=================================================================
Total params: 9,550
Trainable params: 9,550
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

P.S: another way to create input from is passing `type_spec` parameter. If you pass this argument, all other args except name must be None.